# Datetime query not working after conversion from MySQL 5.5 to AWS Aurora

Tags: mysql, datetime, coalesce, amazon-aurora, ifnull

I have migrated a MySQL 5.5 database over to AWS Aurora and have both databases working as expected with one exception. A set of stored procedures that utilise `COALESCE` and `IFNULL` in the `WHERE` clause are not behaving as expected for `DATETIME` parameters / columns.

The definition of the stored procedure in both MySQL 5.5 and Aurora is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`TesterAcct`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_LookupTest`(
    IN paramEmail VARCHAR(200),
    IN paramCreateDate DATETIME
)
BEGIN

SELECT
    UserID as UserID,
    Email as Email,
    CreateDate as CreateDate
FROM Users      
WHERE
COALESCE(IFNULL(Email,''),'') = COALESCE(paramEmail,IFNULL(Email,''))
AND COALESCE(IFNULL(CreateDate,''),'') =  COALESCE(paramCreateDate,IFNULL(CreateDate,''))
;
END
```

The call being used to test the stored procedure is:

```
call usp_LookupTest('pcg@none.com',null)
```

None of the columns for the record being queried are `NULL` and both database instances (5.5 and Aurora) have exactly the same data and objects

In MySQL 5.5 the record returns as expected and in Aurora an empty dataset is returned. I know it is the `CreateDate` clause causing the issue because the call in Aurora does return the record when that line is commented out.

I don't believe this SQL syntax is anything non-standard and have not found any documentation on Aurora handling `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` differently.

Where should I start looking next?

Comment: I wonder what converting `''` to a date does in Aurora.

Comment: Tried replacing that with a placeholder date (1/1/1950) instead of '' to see if there was any weirdness there related to conversions but it didn't change the results.

The CreateDate in the record is '2016-05-22 16:43:38' so the the IFNULL check on that column should resolve to a date anyway and all other records in the table have a CreateDate as well